# Transforming list r

Tags: r, list

Sorry for possible duplication, but I can't even describe with words what I want to get.

Here's what I'm having now (list of lists)

```
id1 one; two; three
id2 one
id3 one; two; three; four
id4 one; two
```

What I need to get

```
id1 one
id1 two
id1 three
id2 one
id3 one
```

so on... Help.
I need this to create Blast2GO custom .annot file from UniProt Retrieve ID table.

Comment: You might be interested in reading about the concept of "tidy data": http://vita.had.co.nz/papers/tidy-data.pdf

Comment: Just do `library(splitstackshape);cSplit(df1, 'col2', ';', 'long')`

Comment: Give `unlist` a try.

Comment: Thank you @akrun, it works! Thanks to all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `cSplit` for this

```
library(splitstackshape)
cSplit(df1, 'col2', ';', 'long')
```

NOTE: Assuming that the second column name is 'col2' and the object name as 'df1'